# Typescript: Having default value for directive

Tags: typescript, data-binding, angularjs-directive

In my directive I have the variable `index`as follow:

```
   export class MyDirective implements ng.IDirective {
    public static factory(): ng.IDirectiveFactory {
        return () => new MyDirective ();
    }

    public restrict = "E";
    public templateUrl = "test.html";
    public controller = DirectiveController;
    public controllerAs = "vm"; 
    public scope = {};
    public bindToController = {
        index: "<?"
    };
```

in controller of directive I set the default value of the index like this:

```
 export class DirectiveController {
    private index: number = 0;...
```

The problem is that when the parent html set the value of `index` it still shown as `0`.

```
<my-directive index="3"></my-directive> //not working still index is 0
```

How can I set the default value and if the value is given use the given value rather than default?

Comment: what does test.html contain?

Comment: The `<my-directive index="3"></my-directive>`

Comment: but your template, the markup of the directive itself, is pointing at test.html.... your directive template should be something like `<div>{{vm.index}}</div>`

Comment: oh sorry my bad the test url is in fact:
<div>{{vm.index}}</div>

Comment: I tried to check the value of index in "compile" and "link" function and if its undefined then set to 0 but it didn't work

Comment: Can you try with a simple controller like  `export class Controller { index = 0; }`? and no `link` function. The `compile` function does not have access to instance state. You don't need any additional code. This should work. It works when I try it.